# How does this javascript code works?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I understand that calling routes() and assigning to x will assign an object fun to it.But calling x.getData() it returns person.How it can return person object which is local to routes function?
I am specially interested in last two lines.

```
var routes=function(){
    var person={
        fname:'Roger',
        lname:'Federer',
        city:'Paris'
    }

    var fun={
        getData:function(){
            return person
        }
    }

    return fun;

}

var x=routes();

console.log(x.getData());
```

Comment: Start with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Comment: Search about "Javascript Closure" or you may find w3schools article good on this.

Comment: read about closures. Your `getData` function use `person` var, it `saves it inside`, and have access to it, so you get `person`. Closures are important things in js, so get time to learn how thay work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's about JS closures and lexical scopes:
Your function `getData` inside the `fun` object has access to the scope of the `routes` object. It's explained in detail inside the "You don't know JS" book.

https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20&%20closures/ch5.md

Comment: A very worthwhile link.  +1 from me.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the flow carefully:

```
var routes = function() {
    var person = {
        fname: 'Roger',
        lname: 'Federer',
        city: 'Paris'
    }

    var fun = {
        getData:function() {
            return person
        }
    }

    return fun;
}

var x = routes();
console.log(x.getData());
```

**First you defined the anonymous function.**

When the anonymous function is called it:

- Defines the object `person` (locally in its internal own scope)
- Defines the object `fun` (also in its own internal scope)

  When it defines `fun` it also defines the method `getData()` which returns `person` - declared in the outer scope (inside the outermost anonymous function which we just described).
- The outer most anonymous function finishes by returning `fun`.

**Then you call the anonymous function.** (Via `routes()`.)

Calling `routes()` returns `fun`, which means you can do `routes().getData()` and it resolves through to that `getData:function() {` declaration.

As we've said, that returns the `person` object from the scope of the outermost anonymous function.  It's accessible to the definition of `getData()` - so it gets resolved OK.

When you called `var x = routes()` you captured the return value of `routes()`  - which is `fun` because that's what `routes()` returns.  You just made a more complicated route to get to `x.getData()`.  Nothing wrong with that!

**So in short:**

`x` is the `fun` object returned by `routes()`

`fun` has a method called `getData()`, which returns `person`

`person` happens to be defined within the scope of an anonymous function - which you executed when calling `routes()` (specifically you did `var x = routes();` - which triggered the creation of `person`).

I hope that makes sense.

It's not "super obvious", but the code is pretty easy to follow if you work through it line-by-line *in order of execution*, keeping a mental note (or on paper) of scopes and variable values.

---

**Update:** Others are providing worthwhile reading links on the subject of JavaScript closures.  Read those.  It'll *teach* you what I've *stated* above.  They're more worthy (IMHO) of an up-vote.  My answer is simply an explanation of the execution of the code you provided - not a walk-through on closures.  :)